# Cordova Push Notification - Register Tags

Tags: cordova, azure, push-notification

How do I register additional push notification tags after the initial registration? The below code successfully registers tags (arrTags):

```
pushRegistration.on('registration', function (data) {
   ...
   if (platform == 'android' || platform == 'Android') {
      // Register for GCM notifications.
      AzureDbSvc.client.push.register('gcm', handle, {
        mytemplate: { body: { data: { message: "{$(messageParam)}" } }, tags: arrTags }
      });
   }
   ...
}
```

Now that the tags are registered, how do I register additional tags? For example, if arrTags initially contained 4 tags, how would I subsequently (at a later time) register a 5th or 6th tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my code - Adding new tags works without reinitializing. Please let me know any recommendations.

Usage:

1. Initialize - call registerForPushNotifications(arrTags).
2. Add or remove tags - call registerTags(arrTags) with a full array of tags
   (less any to be deleted).
3. Unregister all tags - call unregister()

Code:

```
appServices.factory('AzurePshNtfnSvc', function ($ionicPopup, MsgSvc) {
var pushRegistration = null;
var regData = null;
...

/// Push Notification Registration ///
function registerForPushNotifications(arrTags) {
    pushRegistration = PushNotification.init({
        android: { senderID: 'YourID#' },
        ios: { alert: 'true', badge: 'true', sound: 'true' },
        wns: {}
    });

    // Handle the registration event.
    pushRegistration.on('registration', function (data) {
        regData = data;
        registerTags(arrTags);
    });

    pushRegistration.on('notification', function (data) {
        alert('Push Received: ' + data.message);
        MsgSvc.prepForPushNotification(data);
    });

    pushRegistration.on('error', handleError);
}

// Now I can call AzurePshNtfnSvc.registerTags from anywhere in the app
// and delete or add a tag.
function registerTags(arrTags) {
    // Get the native platform of the device.
    var platform = device.platform;
    // Get the handle returned during registration.
    var handle = regData.registrationId;
    // Set the device-specific message template.
    if (platform == 'android' || platform == 'Android') {
        // Register for GCM notifications.
        AzureDbSvc.client.push.register('gcm', handle, {
            mytemplate: { body: { data: { message: "{$(messageParam)}" } }, tags: arrTags }
            // example: mytemplate: { body: { data: { message: "{$(messageParam)}" } },
            //          tags: ["mynotificationtag", "anothertag"]}     
            // site: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-cordova-client/issues/32
        });
    } else if (device.platform === 'iOS') {
        // Register for notifications.
        AzureDbSvc.client.push.register('apns', handle, {
            mytemplate: { body: { aps: { alert: "{$(messageParam)}" } } }
        });
    } else if (device.platform === 'windows') {
        // Register for WNS notifications.
        AzureDbSvc.client.push.register('wns', handle, {
            myTemplate: {
                body: '<toast><visual><binding template="ToastText01"><text id="1">$(messageParam)</text></binding></visual></toast>',
                headers: { 'X-WNS-Type': 'wns/toast' }
            }
        });
    }
}

// Unregister all tags, called when exiting app
function unregister() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (pushRegistration == null) {
            return resolve();
        } else {
            pushRegistration.unregister(function () {
                console.log('success');
                resolve();
            }, function () {
                console.log('error');
                reject();
            });
        }
    });
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update the registration with the tags via recalling this function `AzureDbSvc.client.push.register()`, as the registration itself is transient.

Additionally, you can try to manager the registration in back end, you can refer to [Registration Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn530747.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Gary! That worked. Question, do I need to re-register all tags or only the one being appended? Please see my solution and recommended improvements.

Comment: Through testing I found that all tags need to be re-registered even when appending a single tag. See my solution.